# Is Fibonacci sequence the minimum of unique pairwise sum sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a strictly increasing (condition added per earlier answer of Amitesh Datta) sequence of natural numbers where all pairwise element sums are unique. Can anyone prove or disprove whether the Fibonacci sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty=(1,2,3,5,8,\cdots)$ is the "minimum" of such sequences, i.e., $f_n\le a_n$, for all such sequences $(a_n)$?

Comment: Do you mean $(1,1,2,3,5,8,\ldots)$ for $(f_n)$? Because otherwise this is such a "smaller" sequence in your ordering. (Unless I misunderstood your description of the sequences under consideration.)

Comment: @Dan: pairwise sum uniqueness $\implies$ no repeated elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The [Mian-Chowla sequence](http://oeis.org/A005282) is such a sequence and it begins 1, 2, 4, 8, 13... ; it also grows only polynomially fast, [no faster than n<sup>3</sup>.](http://www.cumc.math.ca/2004/mc.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. Let $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ be any bijection that isn't the identity. The sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by the rule $a_n=f_{\phi(n)}$ for all natural numbers $n$ has the property that all pairwise element sums are unique. However, it's not true that $f_n\leq a_n$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: Looks like a monotonicity condition is needed to make the question nontrivial.

Comment: @amitesh Datta: I have edited the question in response to your clever answer.

Comment: @anon: I just added the increasing condition.

Comment: @Amitesh Datta: any ideas on the modified question?

Comment: Hi @Hans, thanks for your comment and sorry for my delayed response. Yes, I do have some ideas on your modified question but I don't have the time right at this moment to respond in detail. However, when I'm next active on Stack Exchange (in a few hours of time?), I'll try to give you a detailed response.

Comment: @Hans Looks like Michael has provided an interesting counterexample below. Do you think that answers your question? If so, then you can accept his answer! (I don't have anything to add to my answer.)